# Any way to assign terminal output to variable with python?

Tags: python, redirect, terminal, ffmpeg

I need to grab the duration of a video file via python as part of a larger script. I know I can use ffmpeg to grab the duration, but I need to be able to save that output as a variable back in python. I thought this would work, but it's giving me a value of 0:

```
cmd = 'ffmpeg -i %s 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | cut -d \' \' -f 4 | sed s/,//' % ("Video.mov")
duration = os.system(cmd)
print duration
```

Am I doing the output redirect wrong? Or is there simply no way to pipe the terminal output back into python?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`os.system` returns a return value indicating the success or failure of the command. It does not return the output from stdout or stderr. To grab the output from stdout (or stderr), use `subprocess.Popen`.

```
import subprocess
proc=subprocess.Popen('echo "to stdout"', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
output=proc.communicate()[0]
print output
```

Answer (score 3):

os.system returns the exit code of the executed command, not its output. To do this you would need to use either commands.getoutput (deprecated) or subprocess.Popen:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

stdout = Popen('your command here', shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout
output = stdout.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

Much simplest way

```
import commands
cmd = "ls -l"
output = commands.getoutput(cmd)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess 
nginx_ver = subprocess.getstatusoutput("nginx -v")
print(nginx_ver)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import commands
cmd = 'ls'
output = commands.getoutput(cmd)
print output
```