# Can't get redirection to stdout to work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

After figuring out that functions like `os.system()` return an error code (which I don't want), I've tried the fixes from these links:

- [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)
- [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)
- [Any way to assign terminal output to variable with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449250/any-way-to-assign-terminal-output-to-variable-with-python#2449301)

All of the suggestions work, except that my output (this has been tested on at least 5 different commands) all comes out like this:

```
Fixing b'org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.12\n'...
Fixing b'org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08\n'...
Fixing b'org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08\n'...
Fixing b'org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/19.08\n'...
Fixing b'org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08\n'...
```

Why am I getting the **b'** and **\n'** at the beginning and end of each line? Even simple tests with commands like **whoami** print this extra garbage. I tried cutting the string, like this:

```
temp = temp[2:-3]
```

and it cuts from the data I want (**b'org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.12\n'** becomes **b'g.kde.Platform/x86_64/5\n'**) and not the aforementioned stuff.

Comment: use `temp.decode().rstrip()`

Comment: Thanks, @eyllanesc! Works perfectly (and much simpler than the other fixes).